# отображение спрайтов в pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Делаю игру, на подобие цивилизации. Решил, добавить спрайты вместо одноцветных клеток. Но вместо спрайта отображается, только синий цвет. Порядок отображения вроде правильный

```
import pygame as pg
import os
import sys
pg.init()
top, left, cell_size = 0, 0, 50
screen = pg.display.set_mode()
def load_image(name, colorkey=None):
    fullname = os.path.join('data', name)
    if not os.path.isfile(fullname):
        print(f"Файл с изображением '{fullname}' не найден")
        sys.exit()
    image = pg.image.load(fullname)
    if colorkey is not None:
        image = image.convert()
        if colorkey == -1:
            colorkey = image.get_at((0, 0))
        image.set_colorkey(colorkey)
    else:
        image = image.convert_alpha()
    return image

tile_images = {"farm":
               load_image("test.png")}
all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
tiles_group = pg.sprite.Group()

class Tile(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, tile_type, pos_x, pos_y):
        super().__init__(tiles_group, all_sprites)
        self.image = tile_images.get(tile_type)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(
            cell_size * pos_x + left, cell_size * pos_y + top)

def render(height, width, border):
    global top, left, cell_size
    if cell_size < 19:
        cell_size = 19
    if top > 50:
        top = 50
    if left > 50:
        left = 50
#   if self.top < -940:
       #self.top = -940
    grid = []
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            grid.append(pg.Rect(x * cell_size + left, y * cell_size + top, cell_size,
                                cell_size))
    grid = iter(grid)
    for y in range(len(board)):
        for x in range(len(board[y])):
            rect = next(grid)
            if board[y][x] == 0:
                Tile("farm", x, y)
            else:
                pg.draw.rect(screen, colors.get(board[y][x]), rect)
                pg.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), rect, 1)
    for i in border:
        pg.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (
            left + i[0] * cell_size, top + cell_size * i[1], cell_size, cell_size), 2)
    pg.draw.rect(screen, (131, 79, 42), (0, 970, 2000, 110))
```